# Eclipse-CDT - bool, true, and false as could not be resolved

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse is highlighting bool, true, and false as could not be resolved.
Note that the application builds fine.
How to fix this?

My Setup

> Eclipse Version 2021-06 (4.20.0) Build 20210612-2011
>
> gcc version 4.8.5

What I've tried

I've found posts that say to change the following:

First

> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++
> Compiler -> Dialect to -std=c++14 or whatever.

I can't find this option in my properties editor

Second
Select Window->Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Marcos etc. -> Providers Tab

I did this and added -std=c99

no effect, or maybe the wrong std?

Comment: What code and language are you asking about? In C++ `bool` is a builtin type, in C you need to include the `stdbool.h` header (or use the `_Bool`type)

Comment: Did you include `stdbool.h`? And your GCC version is very old, but it is probably unrelated.

Comment: Did you make a C project but are using g++ in your makefile?

Comment: all code is C
including stdbool.h
yeah, it's old, legacy and I'm not orig dev
yes, make is using c++
The project was not orig in Eclipse.  I did an import C project with makefile

Comment: @SRJ This type of problems are exactly why we use gcc for C and g++ for C++.

Comment: oh yeah, not a fan of the mix and match.  But not willing to peel it apart to get syntax highlighting right of the fact that it does compile.  :)

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening here is that the version that Eclipse is providing linting for is different than the one which is being used for building the program. Sync up the properties of the makefile with Eclipse.

You can find build properties at `Project -> Properties -> Build Settings`. Make sure the build command, flags, C dialect, etc are the same as the one in the makefile. Look at the CFLAGS variable of the makefile and it'll show the properties, like C standard, optimization(for debug mode, make sure there's none, use -g no matter what the makefile says because it's probably for release.) and then select the same options in Eclipse.

Most likely, the standard of C in the makefile is C99 but in Eclipse, it's C89 or something like that, in which case, simply modifying the standard will work.

If the makefile uses, g++ but is pure C, the project either uses a bit of C++, so port the project to a C++ project. If it's pure C but uses g++, you'll have to also make it a C++ project and deal with life or if you feel able enough to change the makefile, do so and use gcc. This problem is the most likely.

I don't even fully understand how Eclipse build works and that's why I migrated to Visual Studio Code, there might be some issues with this, feel free to ask for clarification by commenting. AND MAKE SURE YOU HAVE `#include <stdbool.h>` on each file that uses bools.